# update if not inserted in yii

Tags: php, yii

I want to update values in my table, if the values are not previously inserted. Here is my code-

```
function save_data($date, $game, $score) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition("date = '{$date}'");
    $data = array("date" => $date,
        "game" => $game,
        "score" => $score);
    $game_report = new GameReport();
    $game_report->attributes = $data;
    $game_report->save();
}
```

But it keeps on inserting duplicate values even though I have provided the date condition. Why? How do I update and not insert duplicate values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to make an update, you need to do it on an already loaded database model. 
In your case, this can be done as:

```
function save_data($date, $game, $score) {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->addCondition("date = '{$date}'");

    $data = array(
        "date" => $date,
        "game" => $game,
        "score" => $score
    );

    $game_report = GameReport::model()->findByAttributes($data);
    if (empty($game_report)) {
        $game_report = new GameReport();
    }
    $game_report->attributes = $data;
    $game_report->save();
}
```

Also, to avoid sql injection, you should bind your condition params like:

```
$criteria->addCondition("date = :d");
$criteria->params[':d'] = $date;
```

or simply:

```
$criteria->compare('date', $date);
```

Comment: yeah i saw just after pressing the submit button :D

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, this stops inserting duplicate values but it does not update values. For example when the value of score changes, it does not update.

Comment: add a condition like `if (!$game_report->save()) { exit(CHtml::errorSummary($game_report)); }` and see what went wrong, probably it's something with your attributes :)

Comment: Also, i think you want to load as `$game_report = GameReport::model()->findByAttributes(array('game' => $game));` instead of the entire `$data` array

Comment: Ah! Thanks. It was a mistake from my end only. Also, thanks for that little security tip :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I generally do this:

```
$myModel = myModel::model()->findByAttributes(array('atr1'=>$atr1, 'atr2'=>$atr2));
if($myModel == null){
//create and save new reccord
}
```

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it or if Yii has a better way of doing it but it works.